# how can I convert a document (html) to a string var in js?

Tags: javascript, html, string, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a chrome extension that get document (html) from website
is open in browser tab and convert it to string var without using any node.js or jQuery.

Comment: Some basic research should have given you at least a start point for this from where you could have created a more specific code related question

Comment: "without using any node.js". I wasn't aware that nodejs could run in a chrome extension?  Also, if you do not want jQuery answers, don't tag your question with jQuery

Comment: Send an ajax request to said page. The returned text will be said html, before it gets modified by the page's javascript and the browser's dom parser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML`, this will output all the current html for the page as a string for you.